# XSLT merge the same values in several columns

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to create a piece of XHTML out of an XML and a XSLT file.

I was able to merge only the first, second column, but I can not merge a third, which should be merged according first, second column.

XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LIST>
<Row>
    <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
    <YEAR>2000</YEAR>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <artist1>Bob Dylan1</artist1>
</Row>
<Row>
    <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
    <YEAR>2000</YEAR>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <artist1>Bob Dylanas</artist1>
</Row>
<Row>
    <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
    <YEAR>2000</YEAR>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <artist1>Bob Dylan</artist1>
</Row>
<Row>
    <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
    <YEAR>2000</YEAR>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <artist1>Bob Dylanas</artist1>
</Row>
</LIST>
```

XSLT Code:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:key name="cds" match="Row" use="TITLE" />
    <xsl:key name="cds2" match="Row" use="artist" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
    <body>
    <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
    <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Year</th>
      <th>Artist</th>
      <th>Artist1</th>
    </tr> 
    <xsl:for-each select="LIST/Row[generate-id() = generate-id(key('cds', TITLE)[1])]" >    
    <tr>
  <td>
      <xsl:if test="key('cds', TITLE)[1]">
          <xsl:attribute name="rowspan">
              <xsl:value-of select="count(key('cds', TITLE))" />
          </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="TITLE"/>
  </td>    
  <td>
      <xsl:if test="key('cds', TITLE)[1]">
          <xsl:attribute name="rowspan">
              <xsl:value-of select="count(key('cds', TITLE))" />
          </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="YEAR"/>
  </td>
  <td>      
      <xsl:value-of select="artist"/>
  </td>
  <td>      
      <xsl:value-of select="artist1"/>
  </td>
</tr>    
<xsl:for-each select="key('cds', TITLE)[position() > 1]">
<tr>
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="artist"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="artist1"/>
    </td>
</tr>    
</xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I need that this table look like this:

[image]

Comment: From what I see in your input data you have a three level grouping by `Title`, `Year` and `Artist`. For this you need to have a nesting level of three in your `for-each` loops, too. I can only see two levels. So, I guess that is a starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've defined the first key, to group by `TITLE` correctly, but for the second key, you are grouping by `artist` within `TITLE`, so you need a concatenated key

```
<xsl:key name="cds2" match="Row" use="concat(TITLE,'|',artist)" />
```

Note that the pipe character `|` could be any character really, just as long as it does not appear in either of `TITLE` or `artist`.

Getting the distinct `TITLE` elements is done as current:

```
<xsl:for-each select="LIST/Row[generate-id() = generate-id(key('cds', TITLE)[1])]">
```

And to get the distinct `artist` elements within this, you then do this

```
<xsl:for-each select="key('cds', TITLE)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('cds2', concat(TITLE,'|',artist))[1])]">
```

Try this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:key name="cds" match="Row" use="TITLE" />
  <xsl:key name="cds2" match="Row" use="concat(TITLE,'|',artist)" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
    <body>
    <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
    <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Year</th>
      <th>Artist</th>
      <th>Artist1</th>
    </tr> 
    <xsl:for-each select="LIST/Row[generate-id() = generate-id(key('cds', TITLE)[1])]">    
      <xsl:for-each select="key('cds', TITLE)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('cds2', concat(TITLE,'|',artist))[1])]">
        <xsl:variable name="artistPos" select="position()" />
        <xsl:for-each select="key('cds2',concat(TITLE,'|',artist))">              
          <tr>
            <xsl:if test="$artistPos = 1 and position() = 1">
            <td rowspan="{count(key('cds', TITLE))}">
               <xsl:value-of select="TITLE"/>
            </td>
            <td rowspan="{count(key('cds', TITLE))}">
               <xsl:value-of select="YEAR"/>
            </td>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
            <td rowspan="{count(key('cds2',concat(TITLE,'|',artist)))}">      
              <xsl:value-of select="artist"/>
            </td>
            </xsl:if>
            <td>      
              <xsl:value-of select="artist1"/>
            </td>
          </tr>    
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```